# Creating and populating a json object

Tags: javascript, json, pdf.js

I need to construct and populate a json object with values coming from a method.
A bit of background to this: I'm searching pdf documents with a designated keyword and if I find any match, for each match I need to save:
-the whole sentence where the match is found
-the search term (defined elsewhere: the search term is always the same, so it's really redundant here, but I might need it in the json object that's why I'm including it)
-the result (which is the index where the search term is found in a whole sentence and it should be an integer)
So, here is some code. 
I have this function call inside a loop (the loops goes through the pages and then there is a second loop that goes through the text):

```
for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
    lineWithResult = searchPdf(block.str);
    if(lineWithResult != null){
        console.log(lineWithResult + " wordCounter is " + wordCounter);
    }
}
```

and the function itself:

```
function searchPdf(toSearch){
    var result = toSearch.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm);
    if(result >=0){//if match is found
        wordCounter++;
        //console.log("toSearch " + toSearch + " result is " + result + " wordCounter " + wordCounter);
        return toSearch;
    }
    else{//if match not found
        return null;
    }

}
```

SO I need to construct a json object that at each iteration takes in the parameters discussed above:

So, what would be the best way - I'm a bit rusty with json?
I think I would start by creating an empty object like so (if that's even a valid definition):

```
var searchResult = {"Line" : "", "SearchTerm" : "", "Result" : ""}
```

If the above is right, where do I define the object and how do I fill it up with the relevant values? Bear in mind that there will be a lot of Lines, one search term and a lot of Results because the documents (a pdf) which I will use are quite big and can returns lots of matches
thanks

Answer (score 0):

With saying something like that:

```
 var searchResult = {"Line" : "", "SearchTerm" : "", "Result" : ""}
```

You have already defined the object. JavaScript (at this point) is prototypical, not a "class" based language. JSON in JavaScript is not much more than just a plain JavaScript object. If you want to to create multiple objects of that kind, you have various options. I recommend you to read about JS Object creational patterns.

Here is [a good link](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/4-javascript-design-patterns-you-should-know).

That being said, you could do something like that:

```
 // ... maybe inside a function
 return {
     line: myLineValue,
     searchTerm: mySearchtermValue,
     result: myResult
 }
```

There is no need to init something with empty values; you just create the object with the curly brackets.

Hope this makes sense to you; if not, let me know in the comments, and I will try to improve my answer. :-)

Comment: it does thanks, but I eventually used a normal array of objects, thanks!